# 503 ALB health check HAProxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, haproxy, healthcheck, amazon-alb

I have a HAProxy behind Amazon ALB (Application Load Balancer)
http/80 health check is ok, but https/443 gives me 503, even though the site is available & ok

Here's what I see in HAProxy log:

```
4/26/2018 3:19:47 AMApr 26 00:19:47 localhost haproxy[4494]: 172.30.139.183:31696 [26/Apr/2018:00:19:47.961] 443~ 443/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/4 503 213 - - SC-- 2/0/0/0/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
```

Here's my HAProxy config:

```
global
      ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
      log 10.42.74.144:5000 local0
      log 127.0.0.1:8514 local0
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    daemon
    group haproxy
    maxconn 4096
    maxpipes 1024
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA
    ssl-default-server-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA
    stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock mode 600 level admin
    stats timeout 2m
    user haproxy

defaults
      log global
      option httplog
      mode http
      timeout connect 5000
      timeout server 160000
      timeout client 160000
      option httpclose
      option forceclose
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http
    maxconn 4096
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close
    option redispatch
    retries 3

resolvers rancher
 nameserver dnsmasq 169.254.169.250:53

listen default
bind *:42

frontend 9765
bind *:9765 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/current/example.com.pem ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/current
mode http
acl 9765_test_example_com__host hdr(host) -i test.example.com
acl 9765_test_example_com__host hdr(host) -i test.example.com:9765
use_backend 9765_test_example_com_ if 9765_test_example_com__host
frontend 80
bind *:80
mode http
default_backend 80_
frontend 5600
bind *:5600 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/current/example.com.pem ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/current
mode http
acl 5600_elk_test_example_com__host hdr(host) -i elk.test.example.com
acl 5600_elk_test_example_com__host hdr(host) -i elk.test.example.com:5600
use_backend 5600_elk_test_example_com_ if 5600_elk_test_example_com__host
frontend 443
bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/current/example.com.pem ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/current
      http-request set-src hdr(x-forwarded-for)
      http-request set-src hdr(x-real-ip)
mode http
acl 443_xyz_test_example_com_api_v3_host hdr(host) -i xyz.test.example.com
acl 443_xyz_test_example_com_api_v3_host hdr(host) -i xyz.test.example.com:443
acl 443_xyz_test_example_com_api_v3_path path_beg -i /api/v3
use_backend 443_xyz_test_example_com_api_v3 if 443_xyz_test_example_com_api_v3_host 443_xyz_test_example_com_api_v3_path
acl 443_xyz_test_example_com_demo_host hdr(host) -i xyz.test.example.com
acl 443_xyz_test_example_com_demo_host hdr(host) -i xyz.test.example.com:443
acl 443_xyz_test_example_com_demo_path path_beg -i /demo
use_backend 443_xyz_test_example_com_demo if 443_xyz_test_example_com_demo_host 443_xyz_test_example_com_demo_path
acl 443_xyz_test_example_com_guard_host hdr(host) -i xyz.test.example.com
acl 443_xyz_test_example_com_guard_host hdr(host) -i xyz.test.example.com:443
acl 443_xyz_test_example_com_guard_path path_beg -i /guard
use_backend 443_xyz_test_example_com_guard if 443_xyz_test_example_com_guard_host 443_xyz_test_example_com_guard_path
acl 443_xyz_test_example_com_docs_host hdr(host) -i xyz.test.example.com
acl 443_xyz_test_example_com_docs_host hdr(host) -i xyz.test.example.com:443
acl 443_xyz_test_example_com_docs_path path_beg -i /docs
use_backend 443_xyz_test_example_com_docs if 443_xyz_test_example_com_docs_host 443_xyz_test_example_com_docs_path
acl 443_xyz_test_example_com__host hdr(host) -i xyz.test.example.com
acl 443_xyz_test_example_com__host hdr(host) -i xyz.test.example.com:443
use_backend 443_xyz_test_example_com_ if 443_xyz_test_example_com__host
acl 443_abc_test_example_com_settings_host hdr(host) -i abc.test.example.com
acl 443_abc_test_example_com_settings_host hdr(host) -i abc.test.example.com:443
acl 443_abc_test_example_com_settings_path path_beg -i /settings
use_backend 443_abc_test_example_com_settings if 443_abc_test_example_com_settings_host 443_abc_test_example_com_settings_path
acl 443_abc_test_example_com__host hdr(host) -i abc.test.example.com
acl 443_abc_test_example_com__host hdr(host) -i abc.test.example.com:443
use_backend 443_abc_test_example_com_ if 443_abc_test_example_com__host
acl 443_mb_test_example_com__host hdr(host) -i mb.test.example.com
acl 443_mb_test_example_com__host hdr(host) -i mb.test.example.com:443
use_backend 443_mb_test_example_com_ if 443_mb_test_example_com__host
acl 443_fgh_test_example_com__host hdr(host) -i fgh.test.example.com
acl 443_fgh_test_example_com__host hdr(host) -i fgh.test.example.com:443
use_backend 443_fgh_test_example_com_ if 443_fgh_test_example_com__host
acl 443_test_example_com__host hdr(host) -i test.example.com
acl 443_test_example_com__host hdr(host) -i test.example.com:443
use_backend 443_test_example_com_ if 443_test_example_com__host
acl 443_www_test_example_com__host hdr(host) -i www.test.example.com
acl 443_www_test_example_com__host hdr(host) -i www.test.example.com:443
use_backend 443_www_test_example_com_ if 443_www_test_example_com__host

backend 9765_test_example_com_
acl forwarded_proto hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Proto) eq 0
acl forwarded_port hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Port) eq 0
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port] if forwarded_port
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc } forwarded_proto
    cookie idsession insert domain test.example.com
mode http
server c0abff8ff53e7eb0c2871da1d52fc51d0efc5065 10.42.31.29:80  cookie c0abff8ff53e7eb0c2871da1d52fc51d0efc5065

backend 80_
acl forwarded_proto hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Proto) eq 0
acl forwarded_port hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Port) eq 0
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port] if forwarded_port
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc } forwarded_proto
    cookie idsession insert domain test.example.com
mode http
server 4492af01cd1d23a2c4e3d9243cb4e50d09162edf 10.42.55.231:80  cookie 2dd1d23a291dfc49201c2e4afb4e50d033ce6449

backend 5600_elk_test_example_com_
acl forwarded_proto hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Proto) eq 0
acl forwarded_port hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Port) eq 0
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port] if forwarded_port
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc } forwarded_proto
    timeout check 2000
    cookie idsession insert domain test.example.com
mode http
server 23ff4a32aec3cafa9d1fdc8a6591cfc83c8b45cd 10.42.211.19:5600  check port 5600 inter 2000 rise 2 fall 3 cookie 23ff4a32aec3cafa9d1fdc8a6591cfc83c8b45cd

backend 443_xyz_test_example_com_api_v3
acl forwarded_proto hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Proto) eq 0
acl forwarded_port hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Port) eq 0
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port] if forwarded_port
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc } forwarded_proto
    cookie idsession insert domain test.example.com
mode http
server 5f9f2d6d447d598916598880d9389e0170e7e3aa 10.42.68.211:3000  cookie 5f9f2d6d447d598916598880d9389e0170e7e3aa

backend 443_xyz_test_example_com_demo
acl forwarded_proto hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Proto) eq 0
acl forwarded_port hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Port) eq 0
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port] if forwarded_port
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc } forwarded_proto
    cookie idsession insert domain test.example.com
mode http
server fa74d3cf56e66212ec875e0b92c2b670fb99754f 10.42.0.89:80  cookie fa74d3cf56e66212ec875e0b92c2b670fb99754f

backend 443_xyz_test_example_com_guard
acl forwarded_proto hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Proto) eq 0
acl forwarded_port hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Port) eq 0
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port] if forwarded_port
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc } forwarded_proto
    timeout check 60000
    option httpchk GET "/guard/health" "HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: xyz.test.example.com"
    cookie idsession insert domain test.example.com
mode http
server e0c95be63cd81c7671748b7ff8d96e86e3d0b0a8 10.42.208.41:80  check port 80 inter 2000 rise 2 fall 3 cookie e0c95be63cd81c7671748b7ff8d96e86e3d0b0a8

backend 443_xyz_test_example_com_docs
acl forwarded_proto hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Proto) eq 0
acl forwarded_port hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Port) eq 0
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port] if forwarded_port
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc } forwarded_proto
    cookie idsession insert domain test.example.com
mode http
server b40feb86b28112d96aa8af75544dfea594ef32c1 10.42.21.153:80  cookie b40feb86b28112d96aa8af75544dfea594ef32c1

backend 443_xyz_test_example_com_
acl forwarded_proto hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Proto) eq 0
acl forwarded_port hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Port) eq 0
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port] if forwarded_port
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc } forwarded_proto
    timeout check 60000
    option httpchk GET "/health" "HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: xyz.test.example.com"
    cookie idsession insert domain test.example.com
mode http
server 002c117a2eab4ec0accf6343fc48c16896f301f3 10.42.5.159:80  check port 80 inter 2000 rise 2 fall 3 cookie 002c117a2eab4ec0accf6343fc48c16896f301f3

backend 443_abc_test_example_com_settings
acl forwarded_proto hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Proto) eq 0
acl forwarded_port hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Port) eq 0
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port] if forwarded_port
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc } forwarded_proto
    timeout check 60000
    option httpchk GET "/settings/health" "HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: abc.test.example.com"
    cookie idsession insert domain test.example.com
mode http
server c702bff8af5259921616ccaab19cf87b78490fbc 10.42.84.238:80  check port 80 inter 2000 rise 2 fall 3 cookie c702bff8af5259921616ccaab19cf87b78490fbc

backend 443_abc_test_example_com_
acl forwarded_proto hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Proto) eq 0
acl forwarded_port hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Port) eq 0
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port] if forwarded_port
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc } forwarded_proto
    timeout check 60000
    option httpchk GET "/health" "HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: abc.test.example.com"
    cookie idsession insert domain test.example.com
mode http
server 871fdd922c10878663616084dca6df63574c0103 10.42.249.170:80  check port 80 inter 2000 rise 2 fall 3 cookie 871fdd922c10878663616084dca6df63574c0103

backend 443_mb_test_example_com_
acl forwarded_proto hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Proto) eq 0
acl forwarded_port hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Port) eq 0
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port] if forwarded_port
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc } forwarded_proto
    cookie idsession insert domain test.example.com
mode http
server 928e481473de26ee572194a9885ed29281cc50ca 10.42.223.173:8080  cookie 928e481473de26ee572194a9885ed29281cc50ca

backend 443_fgh_test_example_com_
acl forwarded_proto hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Proto) eq 0
acl forwarded_port hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Port) eq 0
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port] if forwarded_port
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc } forwarded_proto
    timeout check 60000
    option httpchk GET "/health" "HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: fgh.test.example.com"
    cookie idsession insert domain test.example.com
mode http
server 6d9f03cdd2515fbe025d0d688d043e34ec45ffcc 10.42.248.45:80  check port 80 inter 2000 rise 2 fall 3 cookie 6d9f03cdd2515fbe025d0d688d043e34ec45ffcc

backend 443_test_example_com_
acl forwarded_proto hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Proto) eq 0
acl forwarded_port hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Port) eq 0
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port] if forwarded_port
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc } forwarded_proto
    cookie idsession insert domain test.example.com
mode http
server 1ea4383c9540dfd7b8e913fbf26f86aeee952c3e 10.42.137.206:80  cookie 1ea4383c9540dfd7b8e913fbf26f86aeee952c3e

backend 443_www_test_example_com_
acl forwarded_proto hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Proto) eq 0
acl forwarded_port hdr_cnt(X-Forwarded-Port) eq 0
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port] if forwarded_port
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc } forwarded_proto
    cookie idsession insert domain test.example.com
mode http
server 1ea4383c9540dfd7b8e913fbf26f86aeee952c3e 10.42.137.206:80  cookie 1ea4383c9540dfd7b8e913fbf26f86aeee952c3e
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think it is because you don't have a `default_backend` for your `frontend 443`

Comment: Yes, adding "default_backend 443_" fixed it. Thanks! :)

Comment: Cool, just add an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `default_backend` for your `frontend 443`